# How to test that subscription?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

How to test subscription inside function, form is an NgForm --> (FormGroupDirective) and form is scoped inside formChanges function.

```
formChanges(form: FormGroupDirective) {
  form.control.get('roles')?.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
    this.selected = value;
  });
}
```

I want to test when roles value change.

Thanks.

Comment: This snippet might not be the best choice at all. You could directly read from roles control everywhere you want to read `selected`. Remove this function, one thing less you need to test.